# How do I remove RSS feeds from themes?

Tags: theme-development, themes, rss

How do I remove RSS feeds from being listed in the HTML source? Like I want to remove the following:

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" href="foo.com">
```

I don't want to remove the RSS feeds by any means, just the automatic output in the theme.

Answer (score 2):

If the theme is a relatively modern one, find this line of code in the functions.php file and remove it:

`add_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' );`

If it's an older theme, then look in the header.php file for the code that adds those.

Comment: Or, if using a child Theme, call `remove_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' )`, in a function hooked into `after_setup_theme`, with a *lower* (bigger-number) priority than the Parent Theme's setup function.